# How to prevent Nodejs Server to crash when request data is not json

Tags: node.js, json, express, post, python-requests

Today my server is ready to receive requests with json objects

I use `app.use(express.json())`

But if I try to send a request with any other type of data, my server crashes. I need to prevent this. How to solve this?

SERVER CODE

```
let app = express();
app.use(cors({
    origin: config.corsOrigin,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'UPDATE', 'PUT', 'PATCH'],
    preflightContinue: true,
    maxAge: 86400
}));

//Server crushes here if i send any other data types 
app.use(express.json({
    inflate: true, 
    limit: '100kb',
    reviver: null,
    strict: true,
    type: 'application/json',
    verify: (req, res, buf, encoding) => {
        if(!req.is('application/json')){
            res.json({'error':'Invalid request'});                   
        }                      
    }
}));

//Server go down too 
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) {
      console.error('Bad JSON');
      res.status(500).send('JSON parse error');
    }
    next(err);
  });



app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(router);
new GameService(new HttpsService(app));
```

I need to ensure that the server doesn't stop when the other data type is sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a custom middleware and put it in just the routes you want to validate:

```js
  const jsonParserMiddleware = async(req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.body || typeof req.body !== 'string') {
      next();
      return;
    }
    try {
      req.body = JSON.parse(req.body);
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      res.sendStatus(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid data.' });
    }
  };

  app.post('/', jsonParserMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    const { data } = req.body;
    const someResponseData = await myFunc(data)
    return res.send(someResponseData);
  });
```

Or you could stick with `app.use`, which will perform the validation for all routes:

```js
  const jsonParserMiddleware = async(req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.body || typeof req.body !== 'string') {
      next();
      return;
    }
    try {
      req.body = JSON.parse(req.body);
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      res.sendStatus(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid data.' });
    }
  };

  app.use(jsonParserMiddleware);
```

P.S: As far as I know, the first argument of a middleware will always be the `Request` object. Why are you trying to get some kind of error?

Comment: const jsonParserMiddleware = async(req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'string') {
      try {
        JSON.parse(req.body);
        next();
      } catch (e) {
        res.sendStatus(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid data.' });
      }
    } else {
      next();
    }
  };
  app.use(jsonParserMiddleware);

Results is :
SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0

Comment: What do you mean result is: ...?? If you are seeing the `SyntaxError` message it is because your error was not caught. This error is coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can update `verify` option to verify body json content.

```
    verify: (req, res, buf, encoding) => {
        if(!req.is('application/json')){
            throw new Error('Invalid request');                   
        }
        
        try {
            JSON.parse(buf.toString(encoding)); // try to parse the body buff
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error('Body is not a json object');
        }                      
    }
```

Comment: Thanks dude butt he server stops even with your tips